How to achieve a git pull from a CGNAT?
I imagine my scenario to be reasonably common, so I am wondering if there is a method to achieve it.
I perform development on my local machine, which is either connected to the internet over my home Wi-Fi, or over my mobile 4G hotspot.
As I am currently working away from home my question is focused on the mobile 4G case.
I initialise a bare git repository on my local machine, to serve as a central backup from which I may pull/push edits.
If I wish to make edits locally, I can git clone the bare repo, issue pull requests, and once finished adding updates, can then git push origin to update the central repo.
The issue I have, is when I wish to add any new updates to a remote machine not on my local network.
How can I run git clone or git pull on my remote machine, to retrieve git info on my local machine ?
The problem arises due to the network set-up, which I have outlined in my solution attempts listed below.
Alternate method
If I host my centralised repo on the remote machine, I can make pull requests locally, perform edits, and push changes back to the remote. This does not achieve my aim of having a centralised backup on my local machine. Effectively, I want to achieve the same as this, but issuing pull requests on my remote machine, instead of pull requests on my local machine.
Attempts at a solution:

In trying to diagnose my network set-up I have found the following on my local machine:


My IP address according to: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ is different to that returned by hostname -I.
Running nmap -sT -p- $(hostname -I) locally, I am informed port 22 is listening for SSH requests, and port 80 is listening for HTTP requests. I assume this to only be true for requests within the local network.
Running nmap -sT -p- ${LOCALIP} on my remote machine, where ${LOCALIP} is my local IP as returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/, returns a time-out error.
Issuing a PING from my remote machine to my local machines IP as returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/, also returns a time-out error.


Based on the results of step (1), I conclude that my local machine has an IP within my local network, and this is returned by hostname -I. I assume similarly, I could connect another device to this network, and it would have a unique local IP - again, only accessible within the local network. The public IP returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/, acts as a router, passing requests from my local machine to the internet, and returning the result. In my reading, I have seen mention of this possibly being a CGNAT setup.

How can I access my local machines ports - eg: over SSH, though ultimately to perform a git clone request - via the publicly visible IP as returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/ ?
Extra info
My local and remote machines both run Ubuntu 20.04 with bash. My mobile network provider is Superdrug in the UK.
I originally posted this question on ServerFault, but as it is not business specific, I am posting here instead.

There is no proof that CGNAT is an issue here. hostname -i is going to return private (RFC1918) IP addresses, nothing to do with your public IP address. If you want to connect to your home PC, one solution would be to use SSH (or reverse SSH) or a VPN. Possibly setting up port forwarding on your router too. The challenge could be the non-static public IP address, but there is dynamic DNS (DDNS).

I suspect this may be a better fit for superuser.com.   If you are behind CGNAT  you would need to overcome that - probably by using a VPN service that offers a static IP address.     OTOH this may be an XY question.  Why not have a centralized repository and just back that up?  If you are running a simple GIT repo  its generally just a bunch of files you can rsync
